# What is the equivalent of Pandas df.loc in excel formula?

Tags: pandas, excel

I'm quite new to excel. I have a table. One of the column is called 'Dates'. I want to slice rows for rows where 'Dates' cell is under certain range.

In Pandas, I would use:

```
df.loc[(df['Dates'] > start_date) & (df['Dates'] < 
end_date)]
```

Comment: Try using `FILTER`.